# Is the expression 'What's one say?' corrent?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, colloquialisms

I've just heard an unfamiliar phrase from a video:

> What's the driver say?

At first, I thought I just couldn't follow what the actor said but I confirmed that what I had heard was right from the script.

I can imagine three similar sentences which are grammartically correct:

1. What did the driver say?
2. What has the driver said?
3. What is the driver saying?

The expression 'What's the driver say?' does not correspond to none of these. Is this some kind of erratic colloquial expression which means one of above sentences? Or, does this mean something different?

Comment: How about "What does the driver say?" -- as in "What does he have to say" or "What does he say about that"?

Comment: Yes, it's a contraction of "what does".  I can't find anything besides "what" that "does" contracts after.  And the version in your title, *"What's one say?" does not work for me.  But "What's he say?" is okay.

Comment: @Greg: ***'s*** for ***does*** is characteristic of *very* relaxed speech, but [How's he know?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22how%27s+he+know%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example, is reasonably common.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [English Pronunciation in Use](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NNdyjJsi41wC&pg=PA62&dq=%22When%27s%20it%20start%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EhpvVf-MJ-S57gby9YKQDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22When's%20it%20start%22&f=false)  (Martin Hewings, 2007)...

> When ***does*** follows a ***wh-*** word<sup>1</sup>, it can be pronounced /s/ or /z/, but isn't left out completely.
>
> *What does he do?* = ***What's he do***?
>   *When does it start?* = ***When's it start***?
>    (not *What he do? When it start?*)

As per [@Greg's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250170/is-the-expression-whats-one-say-corrent#comment544112_250170), this particular contraction is <strike>almost</strike> never used in other contexts. Also, it won't always sound "natural", and unlike more "standard" contractions *(can't, isn't, won't)* there's rarely any reason to *transcribe* it, and your speech won't ever sound stilted even if you never *say* it.

---

<sup>1</sup> [@Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250170/is-the-expression-whats-one-say-corrent/250201?noredirect=1#comment544168_250201) below is highly relevant...

> Note that ***wh-*** word here doesn’t necessarily just mean the interrogative word itself, but the entire interrogative phrase it’s in; thus...
>    *What time’s it start?*
>    *Who in the bloody hell’s he think he is?*
>   ...both work fine as well.

Comment: Note that “_wh-_ word” here doesn’t necessarily just mean the interrogative word itself, but the entire interrogative phrase it’s in; thus “What time’s it start?” or “Who in the bloody hell’s he think he is?” both work fine as well.

Comment: @Janus: Good point. I've added it to my text, on the grounds it's an essential part of the answer that we wouldn't want to lose through over-zealous tidying-up of comments by mods.

Comment: ...I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's *never* used in any other context. I find myself unable to picture (or whatever the word is for imagining an *auditory* phenomenon! :) any native speaker making this contraction anywhere else, no matter how drunk or otherwise prone to sloppy speech. Maybe the right measuring equipment would prove there's no actual **/d/** in my most relaxed rendition of *It'sn't work* (for *It doesn't work*), but I'm sure both me and my audience would *think* the /d/ was present.

Comment: Like other auxiliaries, _does_ can become a [clitic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic). It’s subject to more or less the same rules of cliticisation, too, which means that double cliticisation is not allowed: just like _I’mn’t_ and _they’ven’t_ don’t work, so does _it’sn’t_ not. Only unstressed auxiliaries are cliticised, and _does_ is only that in (a) interrogative and (b) negative clauses. In (b) _not_ is more likely to be cliticised. In (a) _will_ is either clause-initial (nothing to attach to), or follows an interrogative phrase, which is what we have here.

Comment: The only thing that sets _does_ apart is that just like you’ve got _it’s not_ and _it isn’t_ side by side, you’d expect to have _it’s not_ and _it doesn’t_ side by side, too—but only the latter is used. That is a bit odd, but perhaps not very—the _-’s_ clitic to a noun is rather overused already, after all, being both _has_ and _is_ and the possessive marker, and the plural marker: _the kid’s_ = the child is, the child has, of the child, the children.

Comment: @Janus: Yes, to the extent that there are "rules" governing these "clitic reductions", clearly my ***It'sn't work*** violates those rules - which is why I and my audience would naturally tend to think there *was* a /d/ in there somewhere. But I can be a *very* lazy speaker sometimes (even when I'm not drunk! :), and there's not always that much difference between /t/ and /d/ (both of which I might casually reduce to a glottal stop anyway) so I would be prepared to believe someone with a trained ear who assured me I didn't enunciate a /d/ at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It may be true that stressed auxiliaries don't contract, as you say, but stressed "not" does contract.  "You can do it!  No, I can *not*. [or] No, I *can't*", where apparently the stress gets shifted onto what "*not*" is attached to.  (Or maybe that just means "n't" is not really a clitic.)

Comment: @GregLee Yes, _not_ does contract even when stressed; but then that’s not an auxiliary, so presumably not exactly the same underlying process (or at least not necessarily the same). Another hint that that is so is that double auxiliary cliticisations do in fact occur: _he’d’ve_, etc. (unless you see _would’ve_ as a single auxiliary that can be cliticised). Also, I believe Pullum and some others have argued that _-n’t_ isn’t a clitic at all, but an affix, though I haven’t read what they have to say about it.

Comment: It seems to be only inverted *does* which contracts.  After a wh- subject, there is no aux inversion, and no contraction:  "Who does not want an ice cream cone?" -> *"Who's not want an ice cream cone?"

Answer (score 0):

It simply means "What is the driver's opinion on [the topic at hand]?"

> "Should we buy the other company?"
>
> "I'm not sure.  What's Steve say?"
>
> or "What does Steve say?"

It's exactly the same as saying: "What does Steve have to say on the issue?"